# Error Sending email from mcg10@hotmail.com to gmail address : SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: drupal-7

I am newbie to Drupal and i have been setting up Smtp server with the configuration

smtp server : smtp.gmail.com
smtp backup server : empty
smtp port : 465
use encrypted protocol : Use SSL
Smtp Authentication: 
username : my gmail address.
password : my gmail password
Email options: same email address as above.
Send Test email : same email id as above and also tried with different email.
Enable debugging: Yes

These are my configuration.
When i save congfiguration it shows error as

> Unable to Send email, Contact site administrator.

In clear logs i found this error,
"Error Sending email from mcg10@hotmail.com . Why is that hotmail account it is showing even though i put as gmail account. Please anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. It was issue under

> configuration>system>site information

where mcg10@hotmail.com was given default so that error it was showing.

I changed it to my email address and now it s working fine.